# Drag and move the vertical line on the time series data graph to mark and hold

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I want to use Python plotly to mark a vertical line that can be dragged around on a time series data graph.

Share my image below.

[image]

I remember browsing the plotly or dash web pages that previously described the features of this image, but I couldn't find it when I searched again.
If my mistake is, please let me know how to realize this function.

Comment: Hi yuki_s and welcome to SO. Please consider to have a look at [how-to-ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve](/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to use a `shapes` object in a `dcc.Graph`. You have to configure the graph to `editable` to be able to move the shape. You can then use the `relayoutData` property of the dcc.Graph as input in the callback function in order to get the position of the shape on the graph. This is explained in the link below. I don't think there is a way to restrict the movement of the shape, unfortunately. So in your case, there is no way to restrict the vertical line to stay vertical. A user would be able to alter it's angle, for example.

https://community.plotly.com/t/moving-the-location-of-a-graph-point-interactively/7161/2

I've also included some starter code as an example of a movable vertical line on a dash plot.

```
import json
from textwrap import dedent as d
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

app = dash.Dash(__name__)
app.css.append_css({'external_url': 'https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/dZVMbK.css'})

styles = {'pre': {'border': 'thin lightgrey solid', 'overflowX': 'scroll'}}

app.layout = html.Div(className='row', children=[
    dcc.Graph(
        id='basic-interactions',
        className='six columns',
        figure={
            'data': [{
                'x': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                'y': [4, 1, 3, 5],
                'text': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
                'customdata': ['c.a', 'c.b', 'c.c', 'c.d'],
                'name': 'Trace 1',
                'mode': 'markers',
                'marker': {
                    'size': 12
                }
            }, {
                'x': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                'y': [9, 4, 1, 4],
                'text': ['w', 'x', 'y', 'z'],
                'customdata': ['c.w', 'c.x', 'c.y', 'c.z'],
                'name': 'Trace 2',
                'mode': 'markers',
                'marker': {
                    'size': 12
                }
            }],
            'layout': {
                'shapes': [{
                    'type': 'line',

                    'x0': 0.5,
                    'x1': 0.5,
                    'xref': 'paper',

                    'y0': 0,
                    'y1': 9,
                    'yref': 'y',

                    'line': {
                        'width': 4,
                        'color': 'rgb(30, 30, 30)',
                        'dash': 'dashdot'
                    }
                }]
            }
        },
        config={
            'editable': True,
            'edits': {
                'shapePosition': True
            }
        }
    ),
    html.Div(
        className='six columns',
        children=[
            html.Div(
                [
                    dcc.Markdown(
                        d("""
                **Zoom and Relayout Data**

            """)),
                    html.Pre(id='relayout-data', style=styles['pre']),
                ]
            )
        ]
    )
])


@app.callback(
    Output('relayout-data', 'children'),
    [Input('basic-interactions', 'relayoutData')])
def display_selected_data(relayoutData):
    print("relayoutData:" + str(relayoutData))
    return json.dumps(relayoutData, indent=2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```